# Use NVIDIA graphic card as regular resource

Tags: debian, nvidia, hardware, cpu, ram

I don't use my graphic card anymore, but it is still laying there, idle.

Is there a way I can turn it back on and use it just a regular, additional CPU/RAM for my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use video ram as a swap space. Read here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap_on_video_ram
Don't know how it working though.